# different schemas with different tables refer to identical data file

Tags: database, database-design, schema, data-files, multiple-schema

We have ONE DB which has TWO schemas as follows:

[image]

Do the Names from both Customer tables refer to the same data file location?

If not, is it possible to set them into the same point so in case of changing one the other is changed as well?

Comment: You can synchronize multiple databases with the same schema, but each schema has its own file storage.

Comment: Are you asking if the name column of one table is updated, can the other table with the same id be automatically updated too?

Comment: This is not clear. What the data means depends on the database designs. Are you trying to ask about how the databases are implemented? Again, this depends on information you did not give. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. [mre] [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) DDL gives the content of an ERD.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Oracle, you can save both tables in the same datafile depending on your declaration in tablespaces.

If you don't need to duplicate the same data, you can use a synonym, assigning permissions between schemas.